# How to determine if input is correct in a riddle game?

Tags: input, puzzle

I'm programming a basic puzzle game that will involve quite a few riddles. The player will be presented with a riddle and a textbox to put their answer in. The issue is that users can input whatever they want, and this will be difficult to check against the correct answer. For example:

```
Correct Answer: Tree
Possible answers: The tree, A tree, These trees, That tree, Those trees, A large tree, etc.
```

It would be impossible to add in all of these potential correct answers. My original thought was to check if answers match a list of regex criteria, but that didn't work very well either. I also briefly thought about using a neural network or some form of AI, but the game must be extremely lightweight because of the hardware it will be running on.

Is there some kind of algorithm to check if the user input is close enough to the correct answer? How do other riddle-based games do this sort of thing?

Comment: _"but that didn't work very well either"_ Why not?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I had a few friends try it out, and there were just too many possible answers for the riddles that I'm working with, and it's very easy to break/cheat that system. In addition to that, there are things like typos and punctuation that need to be accounted for.

Comment: You may want to research techniques used in old-school [AI chatbots](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/beyond-aiml-chatbots-102) and expert systems (before LLM neural nets) or parser-based interactive fiction games to reduce unpredictable input to a smaller, structured set of canonical forms to react to. Typos can be handled using [approximate string matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

Comment: You may be interested in some of the contents of [NLP(Natural_language_processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). Use a [stopword list](https://github.com/stopwords-iso/stopwords-en/blob/master/stopwords-en.txt) to exclude useless words(like `the`,`that`,`those`...). And do some research of [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). You can also check whether the programming language you use has an out-of-the-box NLP toolkit, such as NLTK in python.